# The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I have the following error when running my BizTalk package in the server:

The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found

Package Description:
Import a CSV flat file into SQL Server using a stored procedure.

[image]

**Breakdown:**

Create Table Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountName] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ServiceAddress] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [AccountNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Accounts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Create Stored Procedure Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAccount]
    @AccountName AS NVARCHAR(150) ,
    @ServiceAddress AS NVARCHAR(150) ,
    @AccountNumber AS NVARCHAR(50)
AS 
    INSERT  INTO dbo.accounts
            ( AccountName ,
              ServiceAddress ,
              AccountNumber
            )
            SELECT  @AccountName ,
                    @ServiceAddress ,
                    @AccountNumber
```

Flat File: Named it sample.csv

```
Account Name,Service Address,Account Number
JOE BLOW,ADDRESS X CITYX IL 61999,932F623Y52
```

I am using WCF to connect to the database
[image]

I am using a stored procedure
[image]

I created a schema for the flat file
[image]

Receive Port Configuration

[image]
[image]
[image]

Send port configuration

[image]
[image]
[image]

I created a message to receive the flat file

[image]

I created a message to send the XML to SQL

[image]

I dropped the Receive component and assigned the Flat File Message
[image]

I dropped the Send component and assigned the Stored Proc Message

[image]

I dropped a receive response component for the stored proc

[image]

Then I dropped a Construct Message component to initialize the XML document and create the map.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I deployed the package to the server, without deploying to the GAC,
Then I registered the component in the GAC manually.

[image]

**In the server:**

I set all the receive and send ports:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Send port

[image]
[image]

The I configure the application

[image]

I started the application:

- Receive Location Enable
- Send Port Started
- I completely stop and restarted the application.

I drop the file, the file disappears and I get the error

**I get the following errors**

> The Messaging engine failed to process a message submitted by adapter:FILE Source URL:C:\Biztalk Test\Sales\SampleFile*.csv. Details:The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found. This error occurs if the subscribing orchestration or send port has not been enlisted, or if some of the message properties necessary for subscription evaluation have not been promoted. Please use the Biztalk Administration console to troubleshoot this failure.
>
> A message received by adapter "FILE" on receive location "ServerReceiveLocation" with URI "C:\Biztalk Test\Sales\SampleFile*.csv" is suspended. 
>    Error details: The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found. This error occurs if the subscribing orchestration or send port has not been enlisted, or if some of the message properties necessary for subscription evaluation have not been promoted. Please use the Biztalk Administration console to troubleshoot this failure.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So, in an odd state for SO, this is too much information and is confusing the question.  There one little tidbit that's interesting.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the subscription on your Orchestrations does not match the context properties on the received message.

Always when you get that error what you need to do is look at the Suspended message and see what it looks like and compare it's context properties with the Subscriptions in BizTalk Administrator.

In you case the issue appears to be that you don't have a Receive Pipeline that has a Flat File Dissasembler with the flat file scheme specified on it which would convert it to XML and publish it with Message Type context property with the schema name

So what is happening is that it it publishing the raw flat file to the message box without a message type, and Message Type is what the Orchestration is subscribing too, and you have no specific subscription rules to are listening for messages from that port that can then process the raw message. So it does not know what to do with the message and suspends it with the above error.

Answer (score 3):

You state:

> "I deployed the package to the server, without deploying to the GAC, Then I registered the component in the GAC manually."

However, this indicates an incorrect deployment procedure for BizTalk Server.  You should **not** have to GAC manually.  Also, you do not indicate anywhere that you registered (Import) the components with BizTalk Server.

Without importing, none of your artifacts are visible to the runtime so there is no schema to be found.

If you are running locally (and you should be at this point) just **Deploy from Visual Studio** and everything will be registered and GAG'd automatically.

If you are deploying to a remote server (which cannot be you DEV/TEST BizTalk Instance), then you must either export a .msi from you build machine or create a deployment package with BizTalk Deployment Framework.